# Get a git repository as a seed (without planning to contribute)

Tags: git

We have a git repository on github. We can download it, or clone it. If it is cloned, you also get all of its history, as well as its branches and some settings (like remotes set to github).

That's all great if it's your project, or you want to contribute via PR, but if you just want the code as a starting point for your project, and do not need updates later on (thus no merges), you do not need a reference to that remote. You also don't need the history etc.

In order to ignore the history, git has the `--depth 1` argument to `git clone`.

What I'm looking for, is a way to "download" a repository to use as a seed, without having setup anything git related (that I might forget to change afterwards). I also want to do it from the command line, not with the download button on github and then extracting (mostly because it's faster).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the Github repository `https://github.com/android/tools_repo` for example, in order to download the latest version of the `master` branch:

```
curl -LOk https://github.com/android/tools_repo/archive/master.zip && unzip master.zip
```

After the command runs successfully, you'll find a folder `tools_repo-master` in the current directory. It's not a git repository but contains the latest code only.

Comment: Yes I thought so, but I was hoping there was some way that git could download it, and run git init. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @K.Gkinis Sorry but I'm confused. You mention in the question "without having setup anything git related" but you now hope that "git could download it, and run git init". If you'd like to create a new branch that's unrelated with the existing history after `git clone --depth 1`, you can run `git checkout --orphan <new_branch> <existing_revision> && git commit`.